# Comparing two tables then replacing information from on table to the other

Tags: sql

I have two tables (table1, table2) that I need to compare table1 column1 to table2 column1. If they match I need to take the info in table1 column2 and replace the info in table2 column2.

After all of this is complete I need to compare table1 column1 to table2 column1. If it is not found show the entire row from table1

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:

```
UPDATE table2
SET column2 = table1.column2
FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.column1 = table1.column1
```

**Disclaimer: please be sure to verify this query does what you want using TEST data that can be discarded and reset

I'm unclear as to what you are asking on the second part, but here's my best guess

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column1 NOT IN(SELECT column1 from table2)
```